# send password change confirmation with devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I want to configure devise to send a confirmation email when the user has changed their password as a security measure.  I'd prefer to re-use my devise mailers if possible.  Any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Untested, but I'd try to do this within your `User` model with a simple `after_update` callback:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :recoverable # whatever

  after_update :send_password_changed_notification

  # attr_accessible, validations, ...


  private

    def send_password_changed_notification
      # Send email with the mailer of your choice,
      # e. g. your existing custom Devise mailer:
      YourDeviseMailer.password_changed_notification(self).deliver if password_changed?
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I would configure the update user action, you can read on how to do that in their [documentation](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise). Check how devise handles confirmations of new registered users in registration action and re-use that code in your new reset password action.

Comment: I am not asking about reset password, I am asking about sending a confirmation email after a user has changed his or her password.

Comment: I updated my answer, either way, it's the same approach. You customize the update user action and add a mailer.